# Get span style onclick div

Tags: jquery

I want to copy the style of the `<span>` inside the `<div>` with class `select_option_colorpicker` and `selected`.

The value of the style must be set/changes onclick.

I want to set the background color of another `<div>` to the style of the selected `<span>`.

The page I want to modify is here: http://www.panel-it.eu/shop/family-sticker/

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="select_box_colorpicker select_box attribute_pa_kleuren-muurstickers">
<div class="select_option_colorpicker select_option"><span style="background-color: rgb(229, 219, 183); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></span>
</div>
<div class="select_option_colorpicker select_option"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></span>
</div>
<div class="select_option_colorpicker select_option selected"><span style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( ".select_box_colorpicker" ).click(function() {
  console.log($( ".select_option_colorpicker" ).hasClass( "selected" ));
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to select to this **div**'s children with first() function , and then you can extraxt whatever you want from that child

So you want to extract its child ?

```
      $( ".select_box_colorpicker" ).click(function() {
         childStyle =  $( ".select_option_colorpicker" ).children();
         console.log(childStyle);

      });
```

This  way you will get this in console :

```
    Object { 0: <span>, 1: <span>, 2: <span>, 3: <span>, 4: <span>, 5: <span>, 6: <span>, 7: <span>, 8: <span>, 9: <span>, 11 more… } test.html:42
```

So if you do this :

```
      $( ".select_box_colorpicker" ).click(function() {
         firstchildStyle =  $( ".select_option_colorpicker" ).children()[0]; // <---------
         console.log(firstchildStyle);

      });
```

You will get the first child , and then go inside like this an select whatever you want

Comment: When I add this.... nothing gets logged

    $( ".select_box_colorpicker" ).click(function() {
    childStyle =  $( ".select_option_colorpicker").first().attr('style');
   consle.log(childStyle);
      });

Comment: log this : $( ".select_option_colorpicker" ).first()

Comment: Everytime I get undefined, maybe this div is set there with another query function.

How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine class selectors to target specific elements having more than one class like `$(".class1.class2")`.

In this case you can access the style of `<span>` inside `.select_option_colorpicker` with class `selected` like:

```
$(".select_box_colorpicker").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).find(".select_option_colorpicker.selected span").attr("style"));
});
```